# Is there a way to style an element differently according to its aspect ratio (portrait\landscape)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Consider the following layouts:**

[image]
[image]

1. The cyan rectangle has a set ratio. That is - The width of the rectangle is derived from the height of its container by a set ratio.
2. The blue rectangle height is set according to the height of the container, its width is set as the rest of the available viewport width.
3. The container of the cyan and blue rectangles can be changed via dragging.
4. Dragging is easily achievable via JS. The layout described can be achieved via CSS.

The end result of changing that viewport size (browser width) and container height via dragging, is that the blue container may change aspect ratio from portrait to landscape and vice versa.

My question -

**Is there a way in CSS to style the blue container according to its aspect ratio? (portrait\landscape)**

I thought about using media queries, but these only query the dimension of the browser and not those of an arbitrary container within the DOM.

Also I don't really like the idea checking the ratio in JS and adding\removing classes accordingly - it feels seems kind of unscalable to inject presentation layer logic into JS like that.

Comment: Well, can't you check at which screen sizes the "aspect ratio" (By talking about `aspect ratio` i'm assuming you want to apply different styles when it's horizontal and vertical) of the blue div and write media queries accordingly?

Comment: @TilwinJoy How exactly? Since the portrait\landscape ratio is determined by two variables (viewport width and container height) there is an infinite amount of media combinations for either portrait or landscape.

Comment: There is no generally applicable way in CSS to style based on aspect ratio. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish with the styles, you may be able to apply them based on a different property that is correlated with aspect ratio. I think the use cases for that approach are few and far between, though. Of course, it's trivial to achieve this with a tiny bit of JavaScript.